# How to create a .exe file using c/c++ for ssh login into remote server?

Tags: c++, authentication, ssh, runtime.exec

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("ssh -i "privatekey" uname@192.168.1.101");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a .exe file for easy and secure my ssh login in windows,
I have used the above command it's saying:

> 'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: I know this doesn't help with your question, but you should change ```"privatekey"``` to ```\"privatekey\"```, since only then will the program interpret it as you typing in actual double-quotes. This should also fix the error, since ```ssh``` is a valid command in the Windows Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use SSH built into machine.. (or it is not available by the looks "'ssh' is not recognized")  you can compile in libssh.

https://www.libssh.org/

https://api.libssh.org/stable/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html
there are examples of exactly what you want to do.